# Remove_If Case-Insensitive with string

Tags: c++, c++11

Can someone show me how to use Remove_If with some case-insensitive comparison?

Currently I do it like:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_literal
{
   enum{value = false};
};

template<>
struct is_literal<char>
{
   enum{value = true};
};

template<>
struct is_literal<char*>
{
   enum{value = true};
};

template<>
struct is_literal<const char*>
{
   enum{value = true};
};

template<typename Char, typename Traits, typename Alloc>
struct is_literal<std::basic_string<Char, Traits, Alloc>>
{
   enum{value = true};
};

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
CustomType<T>& CustomType<T>::Delete(U ValueToDelete, bool All, typename std::enable_if<is_literal<U>::value, bool>::type  CaseSensitive)
{
    for (std::size_t I = 0; I < TypeData.size(); ++I)
    {
        if (CaseSensitive ? std::string(TypeData[I]) == std::string(ValueToDelete) : std::string(ToLowerCase(TypeData[I])) == std::string(ToLowerCase(ValueToDelete)))
        {
            TypeData.erase(TypeData.begin() + I);
            if (!All)
                break;
            --I;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

I want to do this with remove_if some how.. OR at least a better way of doing it than this.. It just looks ugly is all and I decided to optimize the code so I came up with:

```
if (CaseSensitive)
{
    if (All)
    {
        TypeData.erase(std::remove(TypeData.begin(), TypeData.end(), ValueToDelete), TypeData.end());
    }
    else
    {
        TypeData.erase(std::find(TypeData.begin(), TypeData.end(), ValueToDelete));
    }
}
else
{
    //Do I have to forloop and lowercase everything like before then compare and remove? OR can I do it just like above using std::remove or std::find with some kind of predicate for doing it?
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since `remove_if` takes a predicate argument, this should be pretty easy with a lambda:

```
std::remove_if(TypeData.begin(), TypeData.end(),
    [&ValueToDelete](U &val){ return ToLowerCase(val) == ToLowerCase(ValueToDelete); });
```

Comment: This lambda causes G++ to through a very very long template error.. something about char*&. I accept this though because I get the idea and I'll write a lambda that works for my container.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a struct that holds state:

```
struct StringEqualityPredicate {

    std::string str;
    bool caseSensitive;

    StringEqualityPredicate(const std::string& str, bool caseSensitive = true) : str(str), caseSensitive(caseSensitive)
    { }

    bool operator(const std::string& str)
    {
        if (caseSensitive) {
            //...
        } else {
            //...
        }
    }

};

std::erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), StringEqualityPredicate(targetVal, caseSensitive)), v.end());
```

Since you're using C++11, there's likely a more compact, cleaner way to do it (a lambda for example), but my C++11 knowledge is basically non-existent.... :).

This hasn't really accomplished much though other than moving your if block into a struct rather than inline in your method, but if you find yourself doing this in more than one place (or you just want to abstract it a bit), this could be useful.